# TFS - display all code reviews for a changeset range

Tags: visual-studio-2010

How do I display all code review items for a changeset range in TFS? I need to display all changesets with the corresponding code review items for a period of 3 days.

I have TFS Sidekicks installed but cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2012 (not sure if this works for earlier versions) there is a "New Query" option in the Team menu if you are connected to a TFS. From that you can add a clause that is "Work Item Type =  Code Review Response", then maybe add some date range clauses...hopefully this gets you closer to a solution. There are a lot of fields to choose from in the conditions, so maybe there'd be a way to query based on changeset numbers.